# Machine learning: user-based collaborative filtering

Tags: python, machine-learning

**Task:**
What to fix in the class, just as a beginner it's hard for me to understand where I messed up?

**Code:**

Model:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import pandas as pd


class UserBased:
    """
    User based recommendation system.
    This class makes recommendations to the user using User-Based Collaborative Filtering
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        n_neighbors=5,
        metric="correlation",
    ):
        self.metric = metric
        self.n_neighbors = n_neighbors

    def fit(self, X):
        # Training the KNN model and creating a pivot table of training data.
        X_pt_grade = X.pivot_table(index='user',
                                   columns='id_book',
                                   values='grade').fillna(0).astype('int64')
        X_pt_grade = X_pt_grade[sorted(
            X_pt_grade.columns)]

        knn = NearestNeighbors(metric=self.metric)
        knn.fit(X_pt_grade.values)

        self.knn = knn
        self.X_pt_grade = X_pt_grade

    def predict(self, y):
        # Predicting a list of books the user will like in the form of a dataset with tables id_book and predictive_grade.
        y_pt_grade = self._prepare_y(y)
        similar_users = self._find_similar_user(y_pt_grade)
        recommendation = self._recommend(y_pt_grade, similar_users)
        return recommendation

    def _prepare_y(self, y):
        # Converts the incoming dataset into a pivot table suitable for working with KNN model.
        y_pt_grade_with_user_books = y.pivot_table(index='user',
                                                   columns='id_book',
                                                   values='grade')

        # Adding books that are not in the user's ratings.
        id_books = pd.DataFrame(columns=(self.X_pt_grade.columns))
        y_pt_grade = y_pt_grade_with_user_books.merge(
            id_books, how='left').fillna(0).astype('int64')

        y_pt_grade = y_pt_grade[sorted(y_pt_grade.columns)]
        return y_pt_grade

    def _find_similar_user(self, y_pt_grade):
        distances, user_indices_in_knn = self.knn.kneighbors(y_pt_grade,
                                                             n_neighbors=self.n_neighbors)
        distances = distances[0]
        user_indices_in_knn = user_indices_in_knn[0]

        user_indices = self.X_pt_grade.iloc[user_indices_in_knn].index

        data = {'user': user_indices.tolist(),
                'weight': distances.tolist()}
        similar_users = pd.DataFrame(data).sort_values(
            by='weight', ascending=False)

        return similar_users

    def _recommend(self, y_pt_grade, similar_users):
        X_stack = self.X_pt_grade.stack().reset_index()
        X_stack.rename(columns={0: 'grade'}, inplace=True)

        # Dataframe with columns "user weight id_book grade"
        similar_users_info = similar_users.merge(X_stack, on='user', how='left')\
            .query("grade > 0")

        mean_grade_similar_users = similar_users_info.groupby(by="user",
                                                              as_index=False)['grade'].mean().round(2)
        similar_users_info = similar_users_info.merge(mean_grade_similar_users,
                                                      on='user',
                                                      suffixes=('', '_mean'))
        mean_grade_target_user = y_pt_grade[y_pt_grade.gt(0)].mean(axis=1)[
            0].round(2)

        sum_weight = similar_users['weight'].abs().sum().round(2)

        item_score = similar_users_info.groupby('id_book')\
            .apply(self._prediction_calculation, mean_grade_target_user=mean_grade_target_user, sum_weight=sum_weight)

        item_score = item_score.sort_values(ascending=False)\
            .reset_index()\
            .rename(columns={0: 'predictive_grade'})

        return item_score

    @staticmethod
    def _prediction_calculation(similar_users_info, mean_grade_target_user, sum_weight):
        predicted_grade_target_user = mean_grade_target_user + (
            (similar_users_info['grade_mean'] - similar_users_info['grade'])*similar_users_info['weight']).sum() / sum_weight

        return predicted_grade_target_user
```

Model call:

```
test = pd.read_csv("test.csv", index_col=0)
train = pd.read_csv("train.csv", index_col=0)

model = UserBased()
model.fit(train)


test_user = test.query("user==1")
item_score = model.predict(test_user)
print(item_score)
```

Model output:

```
    id_book  predictive_grade
0    168337          9.292738
1      1241          8.903240
2    124924          8.903240
3    398309          8.874651
4    102621          8.874651
5      4326          8.844859
6       293          8.832135
7     31516          8.673894
8     78919          8.637430
9      4081          8.513742
10     3743          8.478779
11     2966          8.478779
12      314          8.430000
13     4079          8.268309
14      330          8.228933
15    12012          8.222570
16   111170          8.124244
17    43554          8.066194
18    13713          8.015141
19   110530          7.734746
20     4080          6.633673
```

**Additional Information:**
In the _recommend method, the calculation is carried out according to the following formula.
[image]

**Link to data:**
https://dropmefiles.com/rf3G0

Comment: Can you confirm that the code is complete and that it functions correctly? If so, I recommend that you [edit] to add a summary of the testing (ideally as reproducible unit-test code).  If it's not working, it isn't ready for review (see [help/on-topic]) and the question may be deleted.